# Key error when trying to plot a .csv dataframe with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, seaborn

I'm trying to plot how many records there were for each month in a chunk of data, and the data consists of records across 19 years. The data consists of ~97000 entries and looks like this:

```
temporal_fires.head()
Out[4]: 
   latitude  longitude  brightness  scan  ...   frp daynight  type month
0   50.1323   105.6714       307.6   1.2  ...  10.4        D     0   Mar
1   50.1268   105.7196       315.1   1.2  ...  16.1        D     0   Mar
2   50.0070   105.5323       301.4   1.2  ...   7.5        D     0   Mar
3   49.4968   103.9302       301.6   1.3  ...   9.8        D     0   Mar
4   50.3259   105.9778       315.6   1.6  ...  31.8        D     0   Mar
```

**CODE:**

```
# use pandas to read CSV files and prepare the timestamp column for recognition
temporal_fires = pd.read_csv("C:/data/filename.csv")
temporal_fires = temporal_fires.rename(columns={"acq_date": "datetime"})
```

Converting a column to pandas datetime format:

```
# recognize the datetime column from the data
temporal_fires["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(temporal_fires["datetime"])
```

Converting month integers to string:

```
# add a month column and convert it from integer to string
temporal_fires['month'] = temporal_fires["datetime"].dt.month
temporal_fires['month'] = temporal_fires['month'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])
```

Plotting:

```
# plotting
sns.lineplot(x="month",
             y=temporal_fires['month'].value_counts().astype(int),
             data=temporal_fires,
             order=temporal_fires.sort_values(temporal_fires['month'].value_counts().astype(int), ascending=False))
plt.xlabel("Шаталт бүртгэгдсэн сар", fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel("Бүртгэгдсэн шаталтын тоо")
plt.title("2001-2019 оны сар тус бүрт бүртгэгдсэн шаталтын график")
plt.xticks(fontsize=7.5, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(fontsize=7.5)
plt.tight_layout()
```

However, this returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\thesis_py38\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-d5cc43d2c169>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/GIS/undergraduateThesis/programming/vector_analysis/fire_occurrence_by_month.py', wdir='D:/GIS/undergraduateThesis/programming/vector_analysis')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.5\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.5\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/GIS/undergraduateThesis/programming/vector_analysis/fire_occurrence_by_month.py", line 22, in <module>
    order=temporal_fires.sort_values(temporal_fires['month'].value_counts().astype(int), ascending=False))
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\thesis_py38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5455, in sort_values
    k = self._get_label_or_level_values(by, axis=axis)
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\thesis_py38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1684, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: May    29064
Apr    17812
Jun    12610
Sep    11394
Oct     6344
Aug     6185
Jul     5690
Mar     2953
Nov      751
Feb       24
Dec       15
Name: month, dtype: int32
```

What's wrong here? I ran the same code but without converting the value counts from float64 to int32, but the same error occurred.

I had no issues plotting this with a simple...

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
temporal_fires['month'].value_counts().plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='firebrick')
```

..., but I wanted a line chart and not a bar chart as the output, but changing the "kind" parameter to line did not look the way I intended it to be (lines were just jumbled).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column and if ned change order use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for `DataFrame`:

```
temporal_fires['count']=temporal_fires['month'].map(temporal_fires['month'].value_counts())
temporal_fires = temporal_fires.sort_values('count',ascending=False)

sns.lineplot(x="month",
             y="count",
             data=temporal_fires)
```